# I should use is or are

Tags: grammar

There is about 16 months between the two photos.

is the above sentence ok, or I must say : There are about 16 months between the two photos ?

Answer (score -1):

When the subject, months in this case, is plural (more than one), you need to use "are". When the subject is singular (only one), you need to use "is".

> There are about 16 months between the two photos.
>   There is about one month between the two photos.

Comment: 16 months can be a period of time.